# Java Swing Timer First Instance Crash

Tags: java, swing, timer

```
  public class Control extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    javax.swing.Timer timer;
    public Control () {
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer (100, this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Control();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == timer) { 
            //some method
        }
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Auto")) {
            this.timer.start();
            auto.setText ("Pause");
        }
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Pause")) {
            this.timer.stop();
            auto.setText ("Auto");
        }
    }
}
```

When I press the "Auto" button, the timer runs, but after one instance of the timer, it stops running and presents the follow error message:
https://pastebin.com/ExtdqkGa

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Control extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    javax.swing.Timer timer;
    Button auto;
    public Control () {
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer (100, this);
        auto = new Button("Auto");
        auto.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(auto);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setBounds(100,100,100,100);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Control();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == timer) {
            System.out.println("Timer finished!");
            return;
        }
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Auto")) {
            this.timer.start();
            auto.setLabel("Pause");
        }
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Pause")) {
            this.timer.stop();
            auto.setLabel ("Auto");
        }
    }
}
```

I simply added `return` to your if statement in the timer block. This is because if `timer` is the object throwing `actionPerformed` then `e.getActionCommand()` will return null.

Timer's do not have actionCommands.

Comment: `Its not a duplicate of that` - well  rarely are questions 100% duplicates. The important part of that link in the accepted answer is: [How to pinpoint the exception & cause using Stack Trace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/2775450). The OP should be able to isolate where the NullPointerException occurs and then ask a more specific question like "why does e.getActionCommand()" return null? Although you solved the problem you haven't given any advice on how to problem solve a NPE in the future. That is the benefit of the provided link.

Comment: Very well. Thank you for mentoring me.